# how can i change magento admin theme in ver 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento, themes, admin

I can't find where to change the admin theme in magento 1.9.2.1
Normally, it should be under this option
System->Genneral->design->themes

But Now I can't find it.
can anyone help?
thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this as per following link

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-admin-theme-in-magento/

You only need to put files that require changes, not whole admin files.

Comment: This is not relevant for version 1.9. It doesn't have "Admin theme" field in Design tab.